# ERROR in name of column created from Conditional in a query for SUM POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

I am trying to get employees total by department but I have the next error in my query

```
SELECT d.id_departaments, SUM(d.num_employees) AS "TOTAL"
FROM employees e, departamentos d
WHERE e.id_departament = d.id_departament AND
    "TOTAL" > 100
GROUP BY
    d.id_departament
```

I got the next error:

ERROR:  column "TOTAL" does not exist

How I do for getting employees total >100?

Comment: You need HAVING, not a WHERE for a condition on an aggregate: HAVING SUM(d.num_employees) > 100

Answer (score 1):

The join between `employees` and `departamentos` seems to be unnecessary, as you don't use any column from `employees` to calculate the number of employees. Also, it is a bit strange that the table `departamentos` has a column to store the number of related employees - it should be calculated on demand and not be stored.

That being said, your query should imho look something like this

```
SELECT d.id_departament, count(e.id_departament) AS TOTAL
FROM departamentos d
JOIN employees e ON e.id_departament = d.id_departament
GROUP BY d.id_departament
HAVING count(e.id_departament) > 100
```

Avoid joining tables in the `WHERE` clause. It not only a very old syntax that makes the query less readable, but also quite dangerous if you accidentally make a cross join between two large tables. Use `JOIN` instead.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y84JtC9O)